# why can't we pass dereferencing pointer to pointer?

Tags: c

i am just trying different was to pass pointer,i came across this doubt.

we can store pointer value to pointer using dereferencing i.e(*p=*q) why not we can pass through functions.

```
void swap(int *p,int *q)
{
int temp=*p;
*p=*q; /** when this is possible**/
*q=temp;
}



int main()
{
 int a=5,b=10;
 int *x,*y;
 x=&a;
 y=&b;
 swap(&a,&b);
 swap(x,y);
 swap(*x,*y);/*why this is not possibel*/

}

   *p=*q when this is possible.
```

1. `swap(&a,&b);` This is possible
 2. `swap(*x,*y);` This is not possible. Why?

Can anyone post good material on pointers in depth.

Comment: What is the type of `*x` and `*y`?  What type is your function expecting?

Comment: function is expecting address?? why cannot it copy the value of x and y..

Comment: the _value_ of `*x` and `*y` are `int`. Function is expecting `int *`, which is either `x` or `&a`. Check ansers below for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, `&a` is equivalent to `x` in your case.

Why do you want `*x` ? Isn't passing `x` is *simmilar* to passing `&a`?

The data type of `*x` is `int`, the data type of `x` is `int *`. Your function is expecting arguments to be passed of type `int *`.

Maybe its worthy to mention [in context of your code]

`void func (int p,int q)` should be called as `func(a,b)`.

That *does not imply*, `void func(int *p,int *q)` should be called as `func(*a,*b)`, rather it should be called as `func(&a, &b);`

Simply use `swap (x, y)`.

*As a sidenote:* `C` uses pass by value method. If you're passing the values as function arguments, inside the function, it will be received in the variables which are in local scope to the function and any changes made to them will not be reflected in the actual arguments.

That's why, you need to pass the *address of the variables*, not the values itself.

Comment: i am not expecting output...when we call a function with parameters it copy the variable why  2nd function  is expecting address??

Comment: @goutham Please check the data types in that case. `&a` is `int *`, while `*x` is `int`. Your function expects `int *`, not `int`s.

Comment: sorry to ask am not getting how you are saying int *x and *y are type of int and int *p in function is type of int *

Comment: @goutham :-) Nothing to be sorry. I understand the problem. Don't get confused. **I _never_ said**, `int *x` is `int`. **I said** , `*x` is `int`, `x` is `int*`. Same way, `p` is `int *`, `*p` is `int`. Clear now?

Answer (score 3):

Your second example should read

```
swap(x,y);
```

As `x=&a` and `y=&b` already.

If you wanted to swap the pointers over (rather than their content) you would need something like:

```
void swapptr(int **p,int **q)
{
    int temp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
}
```

Note the different definitions of the function arguments.

If you want to swap generically, you will either need a macro that passes the type, like this:

```
#define SWAP(a, b, type) do { type _temp = a; a = b; b = _temp; } while (0)
```

or to use a gcc extension, like this:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { typeof(a) _temp = a; a = b; b = _temp; } while (0)
```

Comment: Hi, could you tell me why we need to warp up the function with do-while here?

Comment: @Unheilig - semicolon swallowing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Answer (score 1):

The second one is not possible because in that case you will be using pass by value and not the pointer,and hence, the values in the called function would be changed,but,not reflected in the main method as they were local to that method and you didn't use pointers.

Another possible solution to achieve the solution is,for that you need to change your **function call in main**.
The function call would be changed to

```
swap(x,y);  //don't use dereferenced pointers here as it will result in call by value.

void swap(int *p,int *q)
{
int temp=*p;
*p=*q;  (** when this is possible**)
*q=temp;
}
```

This is done.

Comment: This does not swap anything as the swapped variables are lost on exit from the function.

Answer (score 0):

After `int *x,*y;` the type of `*x` and `*y` are `int`. Your `swap` function expects two `int*` as arguments, not two `int`.

Comment: sorry to ask am not getting how you are saying int *x and *y are type of int and int *p in function is type of int *

Comment: Each expression yields a value. That value has a type. A variable is an expression. That means, in your code `x` is an expression. Its type is *pointer to `int`*. `*x` is also an expression. Its type is `int`. Your swap function expects arguments of type *pointer to `int`*. When you pass `*x` to that function, you are passing a value of type `int`, not *pointer to `int`*.